# Obtener ruta de un archivo Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

tengo la siguiente duda:
estoy tratando de obtener la ruta de un archivo X para luego pasarla a una base de datos.
Vi que por temas de seguridad con Javascript no se puede, pero vi el siguiente codigo

```
$('#inputfile').change( function(event) {
var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
console.log(tmppath);
});
```

el cual me devuelve algo como esto:

```
blob:null/263338b2-f470-4711-a543-2a567bb28118
```

el cual si lo abro en el mismo navegador me descarga el archivo.

en la parte de HTML lo tengo asi:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<h4 id="excel">Cargar archivo formato <b>Excel</b>.</h4>
<br>
<input id="inputfile" type="file" accept=".xlsx" name="archivo">
```

se puede obtener la ruta del archivo, es decir:
C:\Carpeta\archivo.xlsx
Ya sea con JS o php, ya que, necesito almacenar la ruta en una variable para luego enviarla al backend y asi a la base de datos final.

Comment: Creo que estás mezclando las cosas. Si obtienes el archivo vía Javascript significa que estás obteniendo un archivo que está en el cliente. Si quieres mandar ese archivo al servidor, la ruta no tendrá nada que ver con su ruta original, puesto que estará en el servidor. A no ser que lo que quieras es tener los mismos nombres de carpetas en el servidor y en el cliente  ¿?

Comment: la idea es obtener la ruta donde esta el archivo inicialmente, es decir del lado del cliente, luego pasarlo a una base de datos tal cual, la aplicacion funcionara solo en modo local, pero como lo planteas, seria mejor mover el archivo a una ruta por ejemplo del servidor, y desde ahi consultarlo desde la base de datos?

Comment: Pues puedes tener el archivo tanto en la BD como en una carpeta del servidor. Quizá yo preferiría lo segundo, ya que mostrar el archivo desde la BD puede que sea un poco más complicado, mientras que tenerlo en una carpeta te da la ventaja de poder leerlo, mostrarlo, descargarlo más fácilmente o te ofrece posibilidades como ofrecerlo en descarga con un enlace y cosas así.

Comment: Échale un vistazo al 3er párrafo de este enlace (en inglés): https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#file-upload-state-(type=file).